# Passing className to a React/Tailwind component is not overriding the default classes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a button component I built with Tailwind. Eventually I want to be able to call the component and use a different `className` from the default. However, it doesn't override the default `className`.

```js
    const classes = {
      base: 'rounded-3xl px-6 py-2',
      disabled: '',
      variant: {
        solid: 'bg-blue-700 text-white hover:bg-opacity-95',
        outline: 'border border-blue-800 text-blue-900',
      },
    }

    const Button = ({
      children,
      type = 'button',
      className,
      variant = 'solid',
      disabled = false,
      onClick,
      ...props
    }: ButtonType) => {
      return (
        <button
          disabled={disabled}
          type={type}
          onClick={onClick}
          className={cx(classes.base, classes.variant[variant], className)}
          {...props}>
          {children}
        </button>
      )
    }
    // How I want to use the component
    <Button className='px-4 py-0'/>
```

Comment: Could you provide details about the `cx()` function you have called in the `className` of the `<button>` please?

Comment: It's from a package called 'clsx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tailwind-unimportant](https://github.com/mwnciau/tailwindcss-unimportant) plugin for Tailwind solves this problem. It adds a variant that reduces the specificity of the component classes so that they can be overridden.

You'd change your component classes to `-:rounded-3xl -:px-6 -:py-2`, then you can use your button as desired: `<Button className='px-4 py-0'/>`. The classes without the prefix take precedence.

There's also the [tailwind-merge](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge), a JS library that will de-duplicate these clashing classes.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

It seems that your problem is caused by the fact that when you pass `px-4 py-0` as a `className` value to `<Button>`, you end up with this sort of class sequence:

```html
<button class="… px-6 py-2 … px-4 py-0">
```

When two CSS rules have the same specificity (i.e. `px-6`, `py-2`, `px-4` and `py-0` all have specificity `0 1 0`), then the rule that appears later in the **CSS** will have precedence over any in the former.

Thus, I would postulate that your generated CSS from Tailwind most likely looks like:

```css
.px-4 {
  /* … */
}

.px-6 {
  /* … */
}
```

```css
.py-0 {
  /* … */
}

.py-2 {
  /* … */
}
```

And thus `px-6` will always take precedence over `px-4` and `py-2` will always take precedence over `py-0`.

### Solutions

#### `!important`

You could consider using [the `!important` modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier) on the classes you'd like to take precedence, like:

```html
<Button className="!px-4 !py-0">
```

#### Default/conditional classes

You could consider adding the `px-6` and `py-2` classes only when no other `px-*` or `py-*` classes have been passed into the component. There are many ways to do this. For example, by enforcing separate props:

```
const classes = {
  base: 'rounded-3xl',
  // …
};

const Button = ({
  // …
  px = 'px-6',
  py = 'py-2',
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <button
      // …
      className={cx(
        classes.base,
        classes.variant[variant],
        px,
        py,
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

```html
<Button px='px-4' py='py-0'>
```

Or by using the variant pattern you are already utilizing:

```
const classes = {
  base: 'rounded-3xl',
  // …
  size: {
    normal: 'px-6 py-2',
    foo: 'px-4 py-0',
  }
};

const Button = ({
  // …
  size= 'normal',
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <button
      // …
      className={cx(
        classes.base,
        classes.variant[variant],
        classes.size[size],
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

```html
<Button size="foo">
```